# openshift 3 memory quota

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, openshift, openshift-3

I am using **openshift 3** pro to mount an **elasticsearch** server (not ELK).
to do this I'am using this image : 
  -- https://github.com/lbischof/openshift3-elk
only the elasticsearch part.

After installing I am using elasticdump to add data from another server. 
The process is very long and crashing muliples times. during the dumping, the pod is always using ALL the 512Mi Memory quota.

How to allow 1024 or 2048 Mi for my elasticsearch pod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the resource quota by going to the deployment config in the web console and from the drop down menu on right side select 'Edit Resource Limits'. You will need to first ensure your Pro account has enough memory associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was stuck on the 'Edit' menu that refuse to change this part of config.